# IOS Gmail API - How to get "messageId" of an Email with an attachment

Tags: gmail-api, ios8.3

I am using Gmail API for one of my iOS application.[Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get#try-it).I was successful in authorizing the user for Login process. Then I got the list of all mails (Users.threads.list) and the result is shown below.[image: list of all mails]

Now I need to get a mail with an attachment (User.messages.attachment.get).For this I need to pass 3 parameters i.e. emailId,messageId,id.
[image: 3 parameters needed to get a mail with an attachment]

My problem is "How to get this messageId"?

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The threadId you get in your first request is the Id that identifies the thread, and is the same as the first message in the thread. It has nothing to do with the attachment.

My latest message in my inbox has an attachment. I will get it by listing the mail:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?maxResults=1&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "14e8bf63dd00a52f", // This is the message id!
   "threadId": "14e8bf63dd00a52f" // Since it is the first message in the thread, 
                                  // the threadId is the same.
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "01097010197696465829",
 "resultSizeEstimate": 3
}
```

I then use this Id to get the message's attachmentId:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/14e8bf63dd00a52f?fields=payload%2Fparts%2Fbody%2FattachmentId&format=full&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "payload": {
  "parts": [
   {
    "body": {
     "attachmentId": "ANGjdJ9UyXwpB8pVWgFrzmC3UN92YdlMTEF2-At-0zWG88keYXomvYLxZFMoOq7YVC-14VbOqgssCueyDzo103M28HNnUAC-2KSNF5yIK_74BuNqlMXCUar3OFAwVjsS8s8nWQjkreVusTB5Y4XhHNaj7Z7cCKuRFQBSABLfCF75boSHvHSD1RDeOI33e-7y-1JAgn3VN-AFrOQKVEsclVr_QHt2298tLRhyVzJ30ePnOFnZoyaP_uP54XZHMxXsm9YdfzVKtwFiwqlm4IYjQYX5_eNWUaeqbemBot43fQ"
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Then, finally, I use the message's Id and the attachmentId to get the attachment:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/14e8bf63dd00a52f/attachments/ANGjdJ9UyXwpB8pVWgFrzmC3UN92YdlMTEF2-At-0zWG88keYXomvYLxZFMoOq7YVC-14VbOqgssCueyDzo103M28HNnUAC-2KSNF5yIK_74BuNqlMXCUar3OFAwVjsS8s8nWQjkreVusTB5Y4XhHNaj7Z7cCKuRFQBSABLfCF75boSHvHSD1RDeOI33e-7y-1JAgn3VN-AFrOQKVEsclVr_QHt2298tLRhyVzJ30ePnOFnZoyaP_uP54XZHMxXsm9YdfzVKtwFiwqlm4IYjQYX5_eNWUaeqbemBot43fQ?access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "size": 3115,
 "data": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAE1mlDQ1BJQ0MgUHJvZmlsZQAAeJzllWtMk3cUxp_37R2otFCLTNFXxhBZYR2grEII0CEDEbBUoIx09iZUW3jzUhFkUxlG8IYXmMrChhIUlWwuKA4ZzhsToolDzJDhvGA13hBvgwREuw9d5INxyT57Pj15knNyzj_5_R-Af1RH0xYSgDXPxqjiY6lMTRbF6wUXfEjgCU-doYCOSU1NwltrpBcEAFwO0tG0pSlpvulm6_X5vgP6DY-OBxnf3gcAEDKZmiyAoABIcpw6DIBE79SfAZCstNE2gMgGIDHk6owAQQOQMWqVEiBqAYznqFVKgNwNYFyvVikBVjWA8UJDjg1gbwMgzzOa8wD2KYA1yWgqMAC8bgAbDTRjA_jZAIKs1nwjwN8MICBTk0U518xfBygOAqTPhLcEwE85gPTxhDdLBUi9gDbphPd8BggAxCc_FywNDQEAEOI2gO_ncAzVAC6VwMt5DseY2OEY7wE4MqBpumEFU_jvGxUBYMEFXpiNGGhRikPoJ8REClFNDJDh5E7yFYtmDbIZDpuzl5vAfcU7yd8sMLkkuka6zRMqJ2W4F4rqxY88MyU3paVT5nqPTu3w2TojdSbbt92vxD82wH327Q9PB-3_qOrjitDyOZXhexTtEfYoaXR6bP2nL-KXJPQkpST3LbKq3dJbNOZsf-2grs24LceyLMUaTvsVSAp5ReMlT1ffKb2yrqu8deOBLbu3VVSV7KRrzLVL68z1zL6yA983dfw43BzWUtZqb1988trZFZ3S82cuFvdE9gr_HLzWP9B3594D16GYZ1tGnrxY7nC8cbsbpkKOBbDiG3RglJhLrCLOkd6kjexjxbHa2Ar2aU4a5zF3J28-n-B3Cna5MK4ZbvHCmElx7iqRWVzp0SFxnayXnp8S4901VetDTD9C0b6Rfl7-xKyxQMgkwaFybUhV2KVwqUIf0RzFjs6MPRrnE1-VODmpPiVi0Q31loy4LE72xS--0xeYknODl4usw3R_wa-Fe4vXfqlZIysdWXes3Lpx2ubftubu4FU37IquuV67us5v76WG8sbEQ9N-wOHRI4Jjc46vaR88taYjoPPGhcbfyy-XXam7ar-Zdnv4fvfQw7-TRl-8cTsJASR4H-FIRR524Bc8ICgim9hDPCSjyBryJWs5y842sp9yKriB3D7edn6GIMCF4zLkesttQDjoDpGPWOXRKPGe3Oi10Jv3Xve0huklVIpvoJ-HPy9AEOglkwenydeGtIQ9DQ9VFEeciRJGp8fuj0O8MaEnKTH5_CJ12t30rzUffN6tLdNFGsaXnjFXWrT5oYzQdn9l16qDX21am1eWvD5wA3vT1crm7RXVS3YpvvWqHauz1_-xr_tAX9Ojwx7NCS3VrSPtzCnB2aOdyy4EXXT02Hv_6n94Q2LX3D0xGPfk2XDX2AWHw8mqkxDnnwIA90on9PPc15oAnDwDAIsLNJQDi-3AgnNATSLgHwl4GoFUIaBWgLhlADEwE8QDMVgoAvmuUfWukfSu0QM4Mw0AIDIv1Bkopc5i1jM6m-l1DItgxkLoYAAFJXSwwAw9GOhggwnG_2r9f2UzFdkAQJlPFzPmnFwbFUPTFhOlzLfSK2wmRkYl5BmCZVSIXB4KAM7cBQCuCKjNAoATz7RvzP0HbnfbUKLmT0AAAAcQSURBVFiF7ZZbiF1XGcd_67Iv55w5Z66ZadI4aWw1xU6xoAmMpKZY-yREERofFfoiBS_0QehbfapoH0uLiOCrjNBaEZSWktBCoEZTTVNtm6bJtE06M2cu57LP3mvvvdbnw0xLSWeKRcEHXfA97LX35vfjz9rf_uD_6399qU_y8NYzRw4nw-pb5O4-VfhxXHkXlUfln3055Lf0qCefdarz64nHHnvrPyoweP7oCePrR01oLdrpL6Pm7kU1b4bGDAiQ9ZGNHvLXV_F_W0a29NmybDzc_sX3z_xbAnLx_nhrdO2J1M49kMx8HTV9L-gUqTLIupCvQxCIDqJaMxA3wHnk_CWqF14nX82fHF_v_FAtnSo_scD1N-7eZyu71G4unIgnT4GdhcFlZO3PyNo_oLuMDLagrFHVIqpxBDV9BA7dhpqdRdZH1M--xvDy5hnTVd8cXzq18S8LrF68ZwyTPj_WOXw06dwPQZCNM0j3Zeh1oZ_DsIBRBa5G9Y-BO4Cq9kG6H3XoMHz-0yCG8tlL9K_2_uS67sSnlk7lN7L0bgKbNY_bZvNoMv5VYAsZPoW486BHECeQNiEdh3hsp9qoqAWmCTnI613k9FvQr4mPHSZptY-GdvzEbqyPCJw794Xj2OrbSWsfojxS_hFR70KiodmCZgfVnNiu1gyqMY1qTEBjApIOJGNACisl8tIqBE1regYt6Xf-fv_vFm_k2Rs3qrp-1CSgk2OU7jQqvIeNDKgUpSxgdiqACmAqkFmUmUF0B1wTdAwuhg2Q80P0HTOkrw7oFxs_Be7eU-DpM7ffWZv6eJxGVOEt6voykTJAjI3S7YhNCiZGGQtWIK7BHAA7ibJNxMZABBLByMLbgjSFlpnElKPj5xafvvOLZ79xYVeBusxOhnYCyRTD6i9olRFoEFRAVISNWmgzgbJtsClEGtKAsgcgakMco7RBgganoTTQN3DBY1sdbLFJXRZfA3YXcJX7WlCCp0VZvYExEVYpapUQVCComDjqYKJ9EHVQcQxFALsfkgSMhlqhBiCFhqGGoULWFByJiUYtatc7CfxkV4FR4Y64AKNqkzr0sZISaUUtMcGWBBVARSSmg4lmIWqCDSgzjRgDTsADuYJMYKBhoJAM_IaCUUrh5MieZyCrqqmsDPSLKwRVEEnAKEVkYirJqCUnRCWiINExttFBiQBjqJFCHDASwhBkCJKBjKDOhfrtGlcqylKm9hYoavqFJ81XMJHDBo_VChsSXMhwMqRiSM2A2o6ITZM0uw0pBMkg5OALITghVCA1-Drgvafs1QwkkIlnbwFXb2wM9VQy7tFSYSOF0RVGHJE4EuVIdE6qHVaVeBRjk2D7iqgvKAtiFGIVYgQVQbAKbwSnatZVRl_cxp4CPadeU0MWG06jjNpuUwoQUAIqBKwXjPbESmhLxIQIooAEdAqquf216haoXFClJ1DjcKzoHn1TvranQL_yfygzuxjlESZq4RCCjqmJ8dpSB4N4iJUwKTClLYMAUkEAJN6G27Zgh4J1AeVrdFJRuCErUZ-8Ln-_p0BB_FQ20j-u1h1T6RybZDgVU0YxpUooiVBY2ih6QZMpQy-AlOA9KA06EWxLiDseW1ZEwZGqnLXlVbrRAKmrZ_YUWHqovHDPz8Ze7HXDcT09wUC16KpARpNCYgIxsRiGIWKkIyql2apBl4LUICIYEzCJJ27UJE3HmC2Jqj5X5TpVPHrxyfPfvbCnAMDARw_7oX2BFcfEwXmyMGTNW3KboLylYWKcjai1RYCkrjGlbPeAOqBDwFKRRBWd8RLrc65fvcaa2SRK6x_dyDM3blx_rlhunpi4pV-quxrN_SSNObbqiGFIqUKLECbxfhrqDr4aoy4thfOMipqiqHCuxFeOGMd4oyQbrbJ87TJZOfzVb577weM38j6SAMDl-tr3poef-Zxe7h67mRlunZzjXe_p1jFOWZQRCu3RklN5g64EVQRs6Wl4TysJTCeeYXeFa2tvslluvlS11IO7sT6SAACnKfP74t9mfVksSzM_k-xjvnmQm-KbaEubOIyhqhicRZeBpK6YwDNrPPMNmDI52dZ7XLl6iXdXVs_o2pw8u_TQYDfUx0_Fj9wR66r1xER77oHbDywwP3crzdYscTwJqo0OTXSIiEWw3qPKkrzf4_o713nzyjsMe_1fRj3_4MWlRz7RUKqBCEiBFtDm5MJXuO3Ag53x_QuHpm_h4NQ8Y-k00-kEBkOvn1PkI1a767y3tk7W3XyluHzp5-unl04DQyADRoBj-3clHydgPgSfAKaANtBgYf5wtLDwpWh6_51R1GzaZPKQFovKsuVQhsx3V18ZXTh31l26eAUodsBbO9XfufZs9609BdROAu-n0AR2xpwP5rH3m_T778uHKuxAaqAE8h0ZB1Q79z9I4L--_gmfbXbWAo5BKAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
}
```

Comment: When I am using https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/14e8af86776e595b?fields=payload%2Fparts%2Fbody%2FattachmentId&format=full&key=KWgKd6kjZSpI6aKPP1Qy0Ps5 i get {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}

Comment: first i logged in and then used this url to get attachment id, its telling Login required

Comment: @NileshKumar Make sure that you authenticate with the proper scopes :)

Comment: Can we have the discussion in chat group?

Comment: Hi I need your help.I got attachmentId....but unable to use with the URL you gave me as it saying Authorization required. In fact i first authorized ,then got id and then from that Id ,i got attachmentId.....now don't know how to proceed,as I am using google developer documentation.

Comment: @NileshKumar It has to be `access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}` in the URL :) See if that helps.

Comment: This is the url from where i am trying to download an attachment from a mail https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/14e8af86776e595b/attachments/ANGjdJ_Qlajg2jA3UCh5CK4WT7UtFnG4VJMcKQFVKBNg69PIQZBniDN4rdEnvnKvOM68tGdlXHa2lCRacp6bAFjx_um3p1pVbUWCLdgDaksl9zO4z1gjN8eT6-22GLSBqVYbcyXVhG0MAu2IRez_hwgu1ixx5pMrwHu1mGMsvpd6Rme8ceRyoB6Z2vO-20KFNBw22S8msTzOCbAqwnY40sGS-Jb916NTDkhFVTIczCl_vvfWmbTtgl2VCFdqkExS8DMw7DJ6TLkvvdkVdcsWjnUQKS2Kkzli9CiuUY9-Pw?key=AIzaSyAIWLRvXxD8LoZ41dIdo8cfVVJQ_TxNRNw

Comment: I repeat, you have to set `access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}` in your URL. Not `key={YOUR_API_KEY}`.